# Script recuperate data format from a cell in Google Doc

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I have a Google Spreadsheet column with data format like this [image] and when I want to copy this to a Google Doc table I have this format [image: here]
Do you have any idea how to solve it because I don't want the time just the content in the cell as shown in the Spreadsheet table.

Edit: I did a script like this :

```js
var colonne_date_de_projet = 18
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID).getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
          var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
          var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
          var data = sheet.getRange(1,1,numRows,lastColumn).getValues()
        
      
          
          // the second row because the first is not important
           for(n=1;n < data.length;n++) {
```

.....    `child.asTable().getCell(7, k).editAsText().setText( data[n][colonne_date_de_projet-1] )  ;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `getValues()` with [`getDisplayValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues):

`var data = sheet.getRange(1,1,numRows,lastColumn).getDisplayValues()`